# Ruby blocks format

Tags: ruby

Is there a better way to format this code, to make it more readable?

```
footnotes_paragraph.xpath('./small').children.slice_before do |element|
  element.name == 'br'
end.map do |element|
  Footnote.new element
end.reject(:empty?)
```

Answer (score 4):

You could extract out the initial xquery part into a separate method

```
def small_children
    footnotes_paragraph.xpath('./small').children
end
```

Instead of using `do` `end` you could use `{}`. Then just a little reformatting, personal preference but for long method chains I like to start each line with a `.methodcall`

```
small_children
  .slice_before { |element| element.name == 'br' }
  .map { |element| Footnote.new element }
  .reject(:empty?)
```

Comment: I like the braces for blocks with return values ala; http://onestepback.org/index.cgi/Tech/Ruby/BraceVsDoEnd.rdoc

Comment: @garrow that's an excellent standard to have. I will be adopting that.

Comment: In MRI <= 1.8.7, you'll need a \ on the end of each line (except the last).  Ruby 1.9's parser is much better this way.